# Printing a PDF Cognos Report from the Cognos Viewer/Browser print settings overriding report settings

Tags: pdf, printing, cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I have configured a report's orientation to portrait when the output is PDF. It displays correctly in the Cognos Viewer. However, when I click on the Print button on the right side in the Cognos Viewer, the orientation defaults to my browser's page setup setting (Firefox). I can't change the orientation in the Print dialog box, and I am having to go to my browser's Page Setup and change it there.

This is a problem because most users will hit the print button and expect that the report prints how it appears on the screen. These reports are a few hundred pages long and it would be very disappointing to find them printed incorrectly.

Does anyone know how to ensure that the print options you select in your report override whatever your browser's settings are? I am using a Mac.

If there is no solution for this, I would have to remove the Print button from the Cognos Viewer and force the user to Download the report and then print. Does anyone know how to remove the print button?

Thanks!

Comment: I know nothing about Macs, but in general terms, you need to print from Acrobat, not your web browser.

Answer (score 0):

According to the IBM knowledge base [here](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/dm/cognos/infrastructure/portals/adding_and_removing_ui_sections_in_cognos_connection.pdf), you can do so by editing the system.xml in the installation directory of your cognos server.

You might wanna dig a little deeper to see which option you want to disable.

As always use the standard precation like backup system.xml, backup content store, restart your server and services etc.